# Is it possible to internalize Castle Project's DynamicProxy classes using ILMerge?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-dynamicproxy, ilmerge

I have a .NET library that internally has a dependency on Castle.Core.dll, since I use [Castle's DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) (specifically, an "interface proxy without target") to perform interception of method calls for custom processing. Because my assembly is strongly-named, I want to use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) to combine all of my dependencies into a single assembly for deployment, internalizing the types of my dependencies so as to not expose them unnecessarily to my consumers. This is particularly important for the [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) case, where if my assembly is strongly-named, I have to set my package dependencies to the *specific* version of the dependency, or the assembly name resolution breaks, because Castle.Core.dll is also strongly-named. Note that releasing my project as a strongly-named assembly is a feature valued by my users, so removing the strong-name is not an option.

Apparently, DynamicProxy requires some of its classes to be public to work properly. No problem, I can exclude certain types from being internalized by ILMerge. However, my problems occur when I have a user who references my library, but also references Castle.Core.dll. The public types are now provided by two assemblies, and references to them are ambiguous.

If I don't internalize Castle.Core.dll using ILMerge, shipping it alongside my own assembly, this risks version conflicts between my version and my users' versions. If I use ILMerge to internalize the assembly, I'm forced to exclude internalizing the types that DynamicProxy requires to work properly. This approach will break any project that references both my assembly and Castle.Core.dll because of the ambiguous types.

Am I forced into one of these two suboptimal courses of action? Or is there some solution I've not yet thought of?

Comment: you should check out the moq repository. They internalize Castle.Core for dynamicproxy also... https://github.com/Moq/moq4/tree/dev/Tools

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I'll point out that project is using an older version of the Castle project, and they suffer from the same issue.

Comment: Here's another project that debating the same issue. Maybe their discussion here might be of interest to you https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/16

Answer (score 1):

When you have two fully qualified types of the same name, then you're going to run into the issue of ambiguity. This can be resolved using [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx).

By default, all referenced assemblies fall within the global alias, which is why in generated code you'll see something like `global::System.String`. I can't say for certainty how to use an extern alias in ILMerge, but you can use it to disambiguate referenced assemblies. Either way, you can specify your "*internal*" Castle.Core.dll to be aliased as something along the lines of "*castle*", and remove the global alias from it. The downside is that you'll have to modify your code to take advantage of this as such `castle::Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor`.

Here is a good resource that shows you more information, including images: http://www.davidarno.org/c-howtos/aliases-overcoming-name-conflicts-part-2-extern-alias/

---

Keep in mind, that the secondary referenced Castle.Core.dll (by others using your assembly) may contain the same fully qualified type, but by all accounts they are still two distinctly different classes, that is, a method that expects a type of `castle::Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor` would not work by passing in the type `Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor` from the second assembly.